# Codeigniter not maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing

I would expect that `$config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;` would cause the width to be calculated if I only specify a height. I guess I have to provide any large number for the height to make it work?

```
    $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']     = $image_filepath;
    $config['new_image']        = $thumbnail_filepath;
    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
    $config['height']           = $this->thumbnail_height;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct, you MUST specify both height and width. Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the resize will be as close to the target size as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio.

**However**, if you want to make sure it's always a certain height, set the [master_dim](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html) config option to 'height', then  you can set width to anything and it will always make the resize image that height while maintaining aspect ratio with the width. Similar idea works to maintain width.

Comment: Should have seen your answer earlier, I wouldn't have filled my image resizer code with mathematical workarounds if I had lol

Answer (score 9):

@Mitchell McKenna,
Thanx. It helped me a lot.

In my project, the source image could have been of any size.
and i wanted its width of '245' px, with maintaining ratio, 
So,
I just did like this ....

```
$config['width'] = '245';
$config['height'] = '1';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['master_dim'] = 'width';
```

And it worked. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Setting the other dimension to 1 will do the resizing based on the first value. For example if you want to keep width = 700px and calculate the height based on this ratio ;

```
$config['width'] = 700;
$config['height'] = 1; // force resizing based on width
```